# Lectures and labs on the same day as an exam?

Tags: undergraduate, exams

I'm taking a two day workshop at a technical institute, the instructor has said that all accredited courses must have final exams. Fair enough.

Since this is such a short course the exam will be on the same day that we are also being presented new material. This seems very strange to me, to be given an exam after approximately 5 hours of both lectures and labs throughout the day. That being said, I have a lack of academic experience, so I would like to hear from you.

Is this a common practice to have lectures and labs on the same day as an exam (of the same class)?

Comment: Generally, you should wait for more than an hour to accept an answer as accepting so quickly will deter other, perhaps better quality, answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The university I'm at recently had a class with lecture in the morning, lab that afternoon, exam an hour after that, then a quiz the following morning in lecture, and finally a recitation that afternoon. Summer semesters tend to be like this as they are shorter in length than a fall or spring semester. No one is happy with it, but it's what needs to happen to cover all the requisite material.

What would typically happen during a regular semester is that labs can't be moved or adjusted, but usually the following lecture is either shorter of cancelled if it is the next day and the lecture the day of the exam is mostly review. But I must point out it is at the discretion of the professor.

Answer (score 1):

I have not met this scheme for university (or univerity-alike) courses*,

but I have met it for professional training courses and other crash courses that lead to an exam (e.g. intensive courses leading up to exams you're required to take by law in order to be allowed to do/handle certain things).

However, for those courses

- The curriculum is defined, definitive, and well-known
- Exams required by law often have lists of accredited questions which are available. It is sometimes even recommended to study these catalogues as preparation for the exam.
  [(example)](http://blak-uis.server.de/servlet/is/2146/P-4a.pdf)
- And the course materials are usually distributed well before the course.

* Years ago I attended a summer school where I cannot remember whether there was an exam at the end or not. However, the certificate doesn't have grades, so if there was an exam, that would have been more a check for ourselves how good the understanding of the covered subjects was.